# why does z needs to be the zero element of combine function cop

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

I am going through Parallel Scala Collections' aggregate method

```scala
def aggregate[S](z: S)(sop: (S, T) => S, cop: (S, S) => S): S
```

I understand why cop needs to be associative but not the following statement taken from *Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala*:

> The aggregate operation requires that cop is associative and **that `z` is the zero element for the accumulator, that is, `cop(z, a) == a`***

Why does `z` need to satisfy `cop(z,a) == a`?

Comment: I think this is for cases when collection has zero or one element

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc the property must hold in any case, so no.

Answer (score 1):

How does this method calculate things?

- for each element `T` you would have to transform it into `S` element - it could be done by some function `S => T` but authors choose some more elastic approach with `(S, T) => S`, where this `S` *could* be a zero, or it could be a result of some other parallel computation that ended earlier
- to enable parallel combination of elements you are providing `(S, S) => S` - this allows combining any two elements into one

Now, parallel collections has some options to optimize things:

- it can calculate `sop(element: T, z): S` to convert each `element` to `S` and later on combine each result with `cop(result1, result2)`
- it can squash these two operations into `cop(element, otherResult)` if some `otherResult` is ready

These two operations have to be kind-of interchangable to allow this optimization, but there is more to it.

What if you wanted to combine elements like this?

```
s1 s2 s3 s4
 \ /   \ /
 cop   cop
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
    cop
```

It works if the number of elements is a power of 2. For some other number it could do things like:

```
s1 s2 s3  z
 \ /   \ /
 cop   cop
  \     /
   \   /
    \ /
    cop
```

to make task distribution easier.

In general, by assuming that `S` is a **monoid** with associative `cop`, neutral `z` and `sop` providing something like a isomorphism from `T` to `S` with `S + S` addition, operations can easily optimize stuff internally, while making correctness easy to prove. And you could easily change the implementation to optimize it further, or make code simpler. `cop` having `z` as a neutral element/zero/identity is just a part of this requirement.

If you give up on these requirements... then your implementation is easily (always?) broken. Your result could change depending on the order of execution, and parallel computation have no guarantees on the order of execution of any operation: neither in which order elements `T` will be converted to `S` and in which order `S`es will be combined.

You *could* not rely on `z` being neutral... but by making `S` a **semigroup** you:

- would not be able to return `S` always - you wouldn't be able to provide neutral `S` for empty collection, so at best you would be able to provide `Option[S]`
- would not be able to reduce 1-element collection this way as you would have nothing to seed initially to `sop`, do you'd have to use `T => S` instead of `(T, S) => S` (which might reduce a number of optimizations available to algorithm)
- would probably has more complex implementation as you'd have to rearrange merges things so that you'd never would need something like `cop(s, zero)` or `sop(t, zero)` which could potentially simplify the internal code

Comment: thank you! "S is a monoid with associative cop, neutral z" makes sense. 

looks like what is implicit (and which I missed) is z should also be the zero element for sop too, in the sense that 

sop(a,x) = x

sop is more like reduce/fold/scan, where the purpose of z is to introduce the flexibility of returning an an element of different type than elements in the parallel collection.

Comment: Basically yes. In theory you can have `T` which is not monoidal, but then it is on you to make sure that conversion is safe to run as if it was.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by analyzing the signature of `aggregate` and how it works:

```scala
def aggregate[S](z: S)(sop: (S, T) => S, cop: (S, S) => S): S
```

So this says that it will aggregate in parallel the elements of a collection into a new single element. For doing so it will *"split"* (semantically) the collection into multiple chunks to process in parallel, for each chunk it will run the `sop` *(starting from the `z`)* to combine them into a single `S`. Then, it will combine the intermediate results of each chunk using `cop` until all elements have been successfully aggregated into a single value.

Now, why does the `z` needs to be a *"zero"* element? To ensure the consistency of the result!
The idea is that no matter how many chunks you create the result must be the same as if there was no parallelism involved.

Let's see a simple example, we want to sum all the numbers:

```scala
someBigParallelArray.aggregate(0)(_ + _, _ + _)
```

Thus, if instead of `0` we would have used `5` then the result will change according to the number of chunks created; since each chunk will add an additional `5` to the final sum.

Now, you may be asking why do we even need a zero element at all? We may just assume that the chunks are not empty *(like we do with `cop`)*.
And you would be more or less correct *(since the special case of the whole collection being empty or too small can be handled differently)*. But, that would make `aggregate` very limited, since it could only produce values of the same type of the original collection; and you can see that the signature is more powerful than that, it allows you to produce values of any type, as long as that type has a valid *"zero"* and you know how to add values of your current type to the target type.

This is what allows us to write something like this:

```scala
// Collects all the different values in a Set
val distinct = someBigParallelArray.aggregate(Set.empty[Int])(_ + _, _ | _)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very clear and concise. 

"Thus, if instead of 0 we would have used 5 then the result will change according to the number of chunks created; since each chunk will add an additional 5 to the final sum." summed it up!